# How I Check Spelling using Casperjs?

Tags: casperjs

I want to check content spelling for any give page (e.g: http://casperjs.org/) using Casperjs. is any method to that. How I do that help me?

Comment: What about to use the Google spell check API?

Comment: I don't know about it. I want to check spelling for any page. can you please tell me how i do that using Caserjs or Google spell check API?

Answer (score 0):

You can check to one of this Spelling check library

- https://github.com/cfinke/Typo.js
- https://code.google.com/p/bjspell/
- https://github.com/thinkphp/google-spell-check

Three of them in `JS` so you can add them to your code in `CasperJs`